# Get items from Ansible dictionary by key

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the dictionary:

```
sshd_additional_user_cfg:
- name: root
  authorized_keys:
    - key2
    - key3
- name: user1
  authorized_keys:
    - key1
```

How can I select the objects of that dictionary where the name is root, so that I get

```
- name: root
  authorized_keys:
    - key2
    - key3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*How can I select the objects of that dictionary where the name is root?*"**

A: Use filter [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        selected_users: "{{ sshd_additional_user_cfg|
                            selectattr('name', 'eq', 'root')|
                            list }}"
    - debug:
        var: selected_users
```

gives

```yaml
  selected_users:
  - authorized_keys:
    - key2
    - key3
    name: root
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new var with all elements that match with `name=='root'`

```yaml
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      my_new_var: "{{ my_new_var | default([]) + [item] }}"
    when: item.name == 'root'
    with_items: "{{ sshd_additional_user_cfg }}"

  - debug: var=my_new_var
```